# How to manage updates in a springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a springboot application, and I have to manage a particular use case.

Assume that we have a pipeline, where an an order containing an id and an amount is consumed by a kafka topic from IBM/AS400.

This order will be stored in a database, and used in Springboot for aggregations on an upper level of the application.

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Order implements Serializable {
        private string id;
        private String amount;
}
```

Let's assume that we have 2 orders, one with an amount of 500 and another one with an amount of 200.

This two orders will be used to compute a final amount, so the final amount is 700.

Let's assume, that we change the first order from 500 -> 1000.

The first idea was to use `getOne(id)` + `save` to update.

So it would be:

```java
String newAmount = OrderRepository.getOne(1);
orderToUpdate.setAmount(newAmount);
orderRepository.save(orderToUpdate);
```

Since the order is used on an upper level of the application, and that updating this order will do a computation using 10 years of history, which will take a long time, Is there any way to solve this issue ?

Please let me know, if you need more details !

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: So when the order is updated from 500 to 1000, you have to update the total to 1200 somewhere?

Comment: yes exactly, but in a higher level of the application.

Comment: By higher level, you mean a separate application?

Comment: not a separate one, but there is many aggregations before arriving to the final result

Comment: Okay, sorry for asking too many questions - so you want to recieve an update to an existing order, save it(?) and still reduce/minimize the aggregation time in a different thread/process within the same application

Comment: it's normal to ask questions, don't worry - yes update and save, reduce aggregation time within the same application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202279/discussion-between-driss-nejjar-and-aksappy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the aggregation completely, and I don't know how many times in a day aggregation happens, you could do the following

**Assumptions**

1. Aggregation is performed only once a day
2. Aggregated value is stored in a database and is thread-safe

**Steps**

1. Take the new amount, find the difference between the previous amount and new amount
2. Push the difference (as a real number) to a queue
3. Persist the new amount
4. From the queue, which has the ordered list of changed order values, apply the math on the persisted aggregated value, one by one.
5. Audit the changes after each update to aggregated value.

Comment: it was one of the solution I have discussed with my teammate and we wanted to have a confirmation! great, thanks. While sending the amount to Kafka, where could we implement the logic ? is it relevant to do it in the header of the topic ?

Comment: Or may be we can just use Kafka Connect to do the update ?

Comment: No problems in using a sink, though it will be on overhead to manage a connection pool if there are many updates.